# Efficient JSON (de)serialization from/to millions of small files

Tags: json, asynchronous, concurrency, io

I have a list containing millions of small records as dicts. Instead of serialising the entire thing to a single file as JSON, I would like to write each record to a separate file. Later I need to reconstitute  the list from JSON deserialised from the files.

My goal isn't really minimising I/O so much as a general strategy for serialising  individual collection elements to separate files concurrently or asynchronously. What's the most efficient way to accomplish this in either Python 3.x or similar high-level language?

Comment: Sound likely that you would just slow everything down with all the additional I/O and other overhead. It might be possible to process the data in larger "chunks" and tune the size to find a point where the additional I/O was worth it.

Comment: Using 1 file per record is about hedging against data corruption. One bad records won't affect the rest. Can't do that with the standard json load/dump if I write all records to a single file.

Comment: Hedging that way may simply be too expensive...and there may be cheaper ways to avoid corruption if that's a concern, like checksums or other integrity/validation techniques. Processing in chunks would still limit how many records were effected (i.e. still only a subset, but more than one).

Comment: Another idea would be to reducing the I/O needed (which I think would likely be the the bottleneck) by changing format of the data so each file was just a `list` of value instead of a `dict`JSON supports both. This would work if each record has the same fields, because it wouldn't require writing the same fieldname/keys into each file.

Comment: Can't really change the data format as it's fixed by legacy code.

Comment: Sounds to me like you've got control over both the writing and reading, which would mean changing an intermediate format used internally wouldn't affect anything else. If your goal isn't minimizing I/O, what is it exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For those looking for a modern Python-based solution supporting async/await, I found this neat package which does exactly what I'm looking for: https://pypi.org/project/aiofiles/. Specifically, I can do

```py
import aiofiles, json
"""" A generator that reads and parses JSON from a list of files asynchronously."""
async json_reader(files: Iterable):
    async for file in files:
        async with aiofiles.open(file) as f:
            data = await f.readlines()
            yield json.loads(data)
```